# Users are getting logged out on mobile devices

Tags: phoenix-framework

Users are unexpectedly getting logged out, sometimes multiple times in a day.

Originally, I was using storing the user with put_session. I recently switched to using Guardian for authentication but I am experiencing the same issue (calling current_resource would return nil instead of the user).

Some things to note, for both cases:

1. I have not experienced this issue on desktop/laptop browsers.
2. This problem seems to happen after some period of inactivity, but I can't say for sure since I can't figure out how to consistently reproduce the issue.

This has been an issue for about 6 months so I'm really hoping that I can get some help with brainstorming.

Setup:

- raspbian (jessie) over home internet connection
- Elixir 1.5 / Phoenix 1.3

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by many things. The first thing that comes to mind is the mobile OS trying to save memory/battery and destroying the session (and possibly related data).

You could try to have a different auth strategy for mobile devices, using tokens. Then store the token in localstorage, it should persist even if the mobile browser is restarted.

Usually when dealing with native apps tokens are used, so the user dont have to log in every time. This could apply to basic web apps too.

However be careful, tokens have their limitations, and disadvantages, its hard to revoke them, and refreshing them is not simple. Dont store any sensitive info in the token, because its basically public data.

If this is a simple app without any sensitive data you could have the token valid forever, and never have to sign in again (until the token is removed from localstorage) or have a TTL set to something like 24 hours.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have switched to [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) which is a token-based auth library. But I am not sure what you mean by storing the token in localstorage. Additionally, I am concerned because I cannot find anything about my issue online, nor can I debug to figure out the root cause of my issue. It doesn't help that in my research, I found that there are a number of people who discourage using tokens over Phoenix sessions for security purposes.

Comment: By localstorage, i mean the browsers localstore (a key value store). Tokens are still best not to be used as sessions.

http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/